# After reinstalling the Active Directory roles, I cannot see the users and computer objects

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two Active Directory servers, Server01 and Server02, both of them were in the same domain, both run on Windows 2012 Server R2.

Due to some reason, I moved server01 to another office, and I setup the DNS and DHCP servers, these two works perfectly now and I mistakenly removed the Active Directory roles from server01 and I reinstalled the Active Directory roles again and but now I cannot see the users and computer objects, I would like to retrieve these objects I removed,

Question:Can I retrieve the users and computers objects by connecting the server01 to server02?

Please I really need help and advise to resolve this issue. Looking forward for your help and advise..

Answer (score 2):

You can do an "install from media" promotion on server01.  To quote from [TechNet's description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc816722%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) (I edited out references to 2008 because you're using 2012):

> IFM has the following requirements:
>
> - You cannot use IFM to create the first domain controller in a domain.
> - The media that you use to create additional domain controllers must be taken from a domain controller in the same domain as the domain of
>     the new domain controller.
> - If the domain controller that you are creating is to be a global catalog server, the media for the installation must be created on an
>     existing global catalog server in the domain.
> - To install a domain controller that is a Domain Name System (DNS) server, you must create the installation media on a domain controller
>     that is a DNS server in the domain.
> - To create installation media for a full (writable) domain controller, you must run the ntdsutil ifm command on a writable domain
>     controller.

Assuming that your installation meets those requirements--and I assume it does--you should be able to create media from another 2012 R2 server using  Windows Server Backup or Ntdsutil.exe.

Here are some images from [a tutorial that might help you](http://www.msserverpro.com/install-an-additional-domain-controller-from-ifm-install-from-media-in-windows-server-2012/):

[image]

[image]

Those commands create a folder that you can copy to removable media and use during the promotion process.  Look for the "install from media" option.  The rest of the tutorial has even more screenshots, so I recommend you use that for more information.